Uncertainty of ANN outputs as distribution parameters
It is not an uncommon practice to train neural network models via negative log likelihood $-\mathcal{L}(x, y_{true}, \mu, \sigma)$ to estimate both a location ($\mu$) and a scale ($\sigma$), such that $\mu, \sigma = f(x)$, where $f$ is the optimised neural network and $x$ some data.
During training, the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ network outputs parameterise a distribution $p$, the negative log likelihood ($\mathcal{L}$) of which is used as a training objective. The intuition being that the neural network is trained w.r.t how well the estimated distribution explains the training sample, and thus the neural network learns to estimate the distribution of the output quantity corresponding to the data point $x$.
However, I fail to understand how this yields valid prediction uncertainty estimates ($\sigma$) at inference time for the following reasons:

As the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are themselves point estimates, we do not know their associated uncertainty.
If we assume that during training, the per data point estimated $\sigma$'s yield calibrated, heteroscedastic residuals, it is not guaranteed that this will hold for out of sample data (due to covariate shift), assuming temperature scaling and suchlike have not been performed.
If the data are not from the distribution family of $p$ (and so $\mathcal{L}$), the estimated uncertainty $\sigma$ could be further miscalibrated.
$\sigma$ can be reasonably interpreted as an estimation uncertainty due its use in the NLL, but estimation uncertainty is often a poor approximation of prediction uncertainty.

So, for a neural network that estimated $\mu$ and $\sigma$, under which conditions can one consider the scale $\sigma$ to be a valid prediction uncertainty when taking the location $\mu$ to be the predicted quantity?

This is a very broad question, and essentially covers the entire field of forecasting and predictive modeling.
Theoretically, if your distributional assumptions are correct (your point 3) and there is no model drift or only model drift we can capture, e.g., using trends (your point 2), then the various limiting and universal approximation theorems tell us that we will get asymptotically correct predictions. These are strong assumptions, though, and there is no way to empirically determine whether they are met for a given dataset.
Empirically, then, what we typically do is try various network architectures and other variations to find the best performing setup for our dataset(s), write a paper, and repeat the process. As above, this describes much of forecasting. The aim is usually not to get "valid" (in the sense of "correct") predictions, but "better" ones than with competing models, or "valuable" ones (in the sense of "enabling us to make better decisions").
As an aside, there are of course other considerations, like whether we have captured all relevant predictors, and not too many predictors because of the bias-variance tradeoff, and whether our data is of sufficient quality, plus the question of only having limited test data, and the generalizability of our model to "similar" datasets, and so forth. In my experience, these are usually much more important than any guarantees about prediction quality.
